# How to check jquery already loaded or not?can we replace older version with new version programmatically?

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements, exists

I want to know that when i add jquery in page i want to check before i add that does that jquery already added or not if not added then only add else not.

for example i have added jquery `jquery-1.4.1.min`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo SITE_JS;?>jquery-1.4.1.min"></script>
```

after that when i am trying to add jquery `jquery-1.7.1.min`

`in case i didnt know that i have already added or not` so i tried to add it but before that i want to check the version if the jquery with the old version or same then i dont want it to add else add new jquery and disable older one.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo SITE_JS;?>jquery-1.7.1.min"></script>
```

before adding this i want to check does jquery already exist with higher version or not.
how is it possible?

Comment: but how to check is that already exist or not?

Comment: window.jQuery but not just global variable jQuery which if undefined returns error

Comment: You're solving dependency issues in the wrong way. This isn't a code problem, it's a dependency problem. Fix the root cause, not just the symptoms.

Answer (score 10):

Try it like,

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="<?php echo SITE_JS;?>/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>');
 // you should have jquery-1.9.1.min.js on the site url
</script>
```

Comment: nice answer +1 fr this and in this case.. how to check higher version

Comment: @RohanKumar how can i disable previous version of jquery that already loaded

Comment: Look at this for your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915263/how-to-include-the-latest-jquery-file-without-affecting-old-plugins-in-drupal

Answer (score 3):

try this method to check if jquery is loaded or not...if loaded print the version...

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {  
        // jQuery is loaded => print the version
          alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);}
```

based on the version write a logic to load your version of jquery...

Answer (score 3):

use "window.load" event

```
(function() {
if (window.addEventListener) {
    // Standard
    window.addEventListener('load', jQueryCheck, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
    // Microsoft
    window.attachEvent('onload', jQueryCheck);
}
function jQueryCheck() {
    if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
        // No one's loaded it; either load it or do without
    }
}
})();
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187451/how-to-determine-if-jquery-is-running-on-a-page-even-if-jquery-is-after-the-d)